# Magento 2: Get Payment Methods (All/Active/Used)Magento

Tags: magento, magento2

How to get the payment methods in magento 2.
All 3 types:
1) All Payment Methods
2) Active/Enabled Payment Methods
3) Payment Methods that have been used while placing orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Dependency Injection (DI)**

Here is the code that you need to write in your Block class.

```
/**
 * Order Payment
 *
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection
 */
protected $_orderPayment;

/**
 * Payment Helper Data
 *
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_paymentHelper;

/**
 * Payment Model Config
 *
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Config
 */
protected $_paymentConfig;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection $orderPayment
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection $orderPayment,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
    \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderPayment = $orderPayment;
    $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
    $this->_paymentConfig = $paymentConfig;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get all payment methods
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getAllPaymentMethods() 
{
    return $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
}

/**
 * Get key-value pair of all payment methods
 * key = method code & value = method name
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getAllPaymentMethodsList() 
{
    return $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethodList();
}

/**
 * Get active/enabled payment methods
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getActivePaymentMethods() 
{
    return $this->_paymentConfig->getActiveMethods();
}

/**
 * Get payment methods that have been used for orders
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getUsedPaymentMethods() 
{
    $collection = $this->_orderPayment;
    $collection->getSelect()->group('method');
    $paymentMethods[] = array('value' => '', 'label' => 'Any');
    foreach ($collection as $col) { 
        $paymentMethods[] = array('value' => $col->getMethod(), 'label' => $col->getAdditionalInformation()['method_title']);            
    }        
    return $paymentMethods;
}
```

**Using Object Manager**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$paymentHelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Payment\Helper\Data');
$allPaymentMethods = $paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
$allPaymentMethodsArray = $paymentHelper->getPaymentMethodList();

var_dump($allPaymentMethodsArray);
var_dump($allPaymentMethods);

$paymentConfig = $objectManager->get('Magento\Payment\Model\Config');
$activePaymentMethods = $paymentConfig->getActiveMethods();

var_dump(array_keys($activePaymentMethods));

$orderPaymentCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection');
$orderPaymentCollection->getSelect()->group('method');
$paymentMethods[] = array('value' => '', 'label' => 'Any');
foreach ($orderPaymentCollection as $col) { 
    $paymentMethods[] = array('value' => $col->getMethod(), 'label' => $col->getAdditionalInformation()['method_title']);            
}        

var_dump($paymentMethods);
```

**Sample Output of getUsedPaymentMethods():**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
            [label] => Any
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => cashondelivery
            [label] => Cash On Delivery
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => checkmo
            [label] => Check / Money order
        )

)
```

Sample Output of getAllPaymentMethodsList():

```
Array
(
    [vault] => 
    [substitution] => 
    [banktransfer] => Bank Transfer Payment
    [cashondelivery] => Cash On Delivery
    [checkmo] => Check / Money order
    [payflowpro] => Credit Card
    [payflow_link] => Credit Card
    [payflow_advanced] => Credit Card
    [braintree] => Credit Card (Braintree)
    [authorizenet_directpost] => Credit Card Direct Post (Authorize.net)
    [free] => No Payment Information Required
    [braintree_paypal] => PayPal (Braintree)
    [paypal_billing_agreement] => PayPal Billing Agreement
    [payflow_express_bml] => PayPal Credit
    [paypal_express_bml] => PayPal Credit
    [paypal_express] => PayPal Express Checkout
    [payflow_express] => PayPal Express Checkout Payflow Edition
    [hosted_pro] => Payment by cards or by PayPal account
    [purchaseorder] => Purchase Order
    [braintree_cc_vault] => Stored Cards (Braintree)
    [payflowpro_cc_vault] => Stored Cards (Payflow Pro)
)
```

Sample Output of getAllPaymentMethods():

```
Array
(
    [free] => Array
        (
            [active] => 1
            [model] => Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Free
            [order_status] => pending
            [title] => No Payment Information Required
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [sort_order] => 1
            [group] => offline
        )

    [substitution] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [model] => Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Substitution
            [allowspecific] => 0
        )

    [vault] => Array
        (
            [debug] => 1
            [model] => Magento\Vault\Model\VaultPaymentInterface
        )

    [checkmo] => Array
        (
            [active] => 1
            [model] => Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo
            [order_status] => pending
            [title] => Check / Money order
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [group] => offline
        )

    [purchaseorder] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [model] => Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder
            [order_status] => pending
            [title] => Purchase Order
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [group] => offline
        )

    [banktransfer] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [model] => Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Banktransfer
            [order_status] => pending
            [title] => Bank Transfer Payment
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [group] => offline
        )

    [cashondelivery] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [model] => Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery
            [order_status] => pending
            [title] => Cash On Delivery
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [group] => offline
        )

    [paypal_express] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Express
            [title] => PayPal Express Checkout
            [payment_action] => Authorization
            [solution_type] => Mark
            [line_items_enabled] => 1
            [visible_on_cart] => 1
            [visible_on_product] => 1
            [allow_ba_signup] => never
            [group] => paypal
            [authorization_honor_period] => 3
            [order_valid_period] => 29
            [child_authorization_number] => 1
            [verify_peer] => 1
            [skip_order_review_step] => 1
        )

    [paypal_express_bml] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Bml
            [title] => PayPal Credit
            [group] => paypal
        )

    [payflow_express] => Array
        (
            [title] => PayPal Express Checkout Payflow Edition
            [payment_action] => Authorization
            [line_items_enabled] => 1
            [visible_on_cart] => 1
            [visible_on_product] => 1
            [group] => paypal
            [verify_peer] => 1
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\PayflowExpress
        )

    [payflow_express_bml] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Bml
            [title] => PayPal Credit
            [group] => paypal
        )

    [payflowpro] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent
            [title] => Credit Card
            [payment_action] => Authorization
            [cctypes] => AE,VI
            [useccv] => 1
            [tender] => C
            [verbosity] => MEDIUM
            [user] => 
            [pwd] => 
            [group] => paypal
            [verify_peer] => 1
            [date_delim] => 
            [ccfields] => csc,expdate,acct
            [place_order_url] => paypal/transparent/requestSecureToken
            [cgi_url_test_mode] => https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com
            [cgi_url] => https://payflowlink.paypal.com
            [transaction_url_test_mode] => https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com
            [transaction_url] => https://payflowpro.paypal.com
            [avs_street] => 0
            [avs_zip] => 0
            [avs_international] => 0
            [avs_security_code] => 1
            [cc_year_length] => 2
            [can_authorize_vault] => 1
            [can_capture_vault] => 1
        )

    [payflowpro_cc_vault] => Array
        (
            [model] => PayflowProCreditCardVaultFacade
            [title] => Stored Cards (Payflow Pro)
        )

    [paypal_billing_agreement] => Array
        (
            [active] => 1
            [allow_billing_agreement_wizard] => 1
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Method\Agreement
            [title] => PayPal Billing Agreement
            [group] => paypal
            [verify_peer] => 1
        )

    [payflow_link] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowlink
            [payment_action] => Authorization
            [verbosity] => HIGH
            [user] => 
            [pwd] => 
            [group] => paypal
            [title] => Credit Card
            [partner] => PayPal
            [csc_required] => 1
            [csc_editable] => 1
            [url_method] => GET
            [email_confirmation] => 0
            [verify_peer] => 1
            [transaction_url_test_mode] => https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com
            [transaction_url] => https://payflowpro.paypal.com
            [cgi_url_test_mode] => https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com
            [cgi_url] => https://payflowlink.paypal.com
        )

    [payflow_advanced] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflowadvanced
            [payment_action] => Authorization
            [verbosity] => HIGH
            [user] => PayPal
            [pwd] => 
            [group] => paypal
            [title] => Credit Card
            [partner] => PayPal
            [vendor] => PayPal
            [csc_required] => 1
            [csc_editable] => 1
            [url_method] => GET
            [email_confirmation] => 0
            [verify_peer] => 1
            [transaction_url_test_mode] => https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com
            [transaction_url] => https://payflowpro.paypal.com
            [cgi_url_test_mode] => https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com
            [cgi_url] => https://payflowlink.paypal.com
        )

    [hosted_pro] => Array
        (
            [model] => Magento\Paypal\Model\Hostedpro
            [title] => Payment by cards or by PayPal account
            [payment_action] => Authorization
            [group] => paypal
            [display_ec] => 0
            [verify_peer] => 1
        )

    [authorizenet_directpost] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [cctypes] => AE,VI,MC,DI
            [debug] => 0
            [email_customer] => 0
            [login] => 
            [merchant_email] => 
            [model] => Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost
            [order_status] => processing
            [payment_action] => authorize
            [test] => 1
            [title] => Credit Card Direct Post (Authorize.net)
            [trans_key] => 
            [trans_md5] => 
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [currency] => USD
            [create_order_before] => 1
            [date_delim] => /
            [ccfields] => x_card_code,x_exp_date,x_card_num
            [place_order_url] => authorizenet/directpost_payment/place
            [cgi_url_test_mode] => https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
            [cgi_url] => https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
            [cgi_url_td_test_mode] => https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
            [cgi_url_td] => https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
        )

    [braintree] => Array
        (
            [model] => BraintreeFacade
            [title] => Credit Card (Braintree)
            [payment_action] => authorize
            [active] => 0
            [is_gateway] => 1
            [can_use_checkout] => 1
            [can_authorize] => 1
            [can_capture] => 1
            [can_capture_partial] => 1
            [can_authorize_vault] => 1
            [can_capture_vault] => 1
            [can_use_internal] => 1
            [can_refund_partial_per_invoice] => 1
            [can_refund] => 1
            [can_void] => 1
            [can_cancel] => 1
            [cctypes] => AE,VI,MC,DI,JCB,CUP,DN,MI
            [useccv] => 1
            [cctypes_braintree_mapper] => {"american-express":"AE","discover":"DI","jcb":"JCB","mastercard":"MC","master-card":"MC","visa":"VI","maestro":"MI","diners-club":"DN","unionpay":"CUP"}
            [order_status] => processing
            [environment] => sandbox
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [sdk_url] => https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.17.6.min.js
            [public_key] => 
            [private_key] => 
            [masked_fields] => cvv,number
            [privateInfoKeys] => avsPostalCodeResponseCode,avsStreetAddressResponseCode,cvvResponseCode,processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,liabilityShifted,liabilityShiftPossible,riskDataId,riskDataDecision
            [paymentInfoKeys] => cc_type,cc_number,avsPostalCodeResponseCode,avsStreetAddressResponseCode,cvvResponseCode,processorAuthorizationCode,processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,liabilityShifted,liabilityShiftPossible,riskDataId,riskDataDecision
        )

    [braintree_paypal] => Array
        (
            [model] => BraintreePayPalFacade
            [title] => PayPal (Braintree)
            [active] => 0
            [payment_action] => authorize
            [allowspecific] => 0
            [require_billing_address] => 0
            [allow_shipping_address_override] => 1
            [display_on_shopping_cart] => 1
            [order_status] => processing
            [is_gateway] => 1
            [can_use_checkout] => 1
            [can_authorize] => 1
            [can_capture] => 1
            [can_capture_partial] => 1
            [can_refund] => 1
            [can_refund_partial_per_invoice] => 1
            [can_void] => 1
            [can_cancel] => 1
            [privateInfoKeys] => processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,paymentId
            [paymentInfoKeys] => processorResponseCode,processorResponseText,paymentId,payerEmail
        )

    [braintree_cc_vault] => Array
        (
            [model] => BraintreeCreditCardVaultFacade
            [title] => Stored Cards (Braintree)
        )
```

The output array of of getActivePaymentMethods() is very long. So, I have just printed out the keys of the array. Keys of the output array contains active method’s code.

Sample Output of array_keys(getActivePaymentMethods()):

```
Array
(
    [0] => free
    [1] => checkmo
    [2] => purchaseorder
    [3] => cashondelivery
    [4] => paypal_billing_agreement
)
```